# Python Polars Read Zipped CSV

Tags: python-polars

How does one read a zipped csv file into a python `polars` DataFrame?

The only current solution is writing the entire thing into memory and then passing it into `pl.read_csv`.

Comment: I think you could use a reader. I.e. something like this?
```with file.open(csv_path) as fpz:
    with gzip.open(fpz) as fp:
        df = pl.read_csv(fp)```

Comment: Apologies, it's zipped, not gzipped

Answer (score 4):

##### Read a zipped csv file into Polars Dataframe without extracting the file

From the documentation:

> Path to a file or a file-like object. By file-like object, we refer to objects with a `read()` method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or `StringIO` or `BytesIO`. If fsspec is installed, it will be used to open remote files.

So, to read "my_file.csv" that is inside a "something.zip":

```
    /something.zip

        /my_file.csv
```

```py
import polars as pl
from zipfile import ZipFile


zip_file = "something.zip"

pl.read_csv(
    Zipfile("something.zip").read("my_file.csv")
)
```

Here, the use of `.open` instead of `.read` throws a `FileNotFound` error.
However, it is still possible to use `open`, we just need to call `.read()`, as follows:

```py
pl.read_csv(
    Zipfile("something.zip").open("my_file.csv", method='r').read()
)
```

The difference lies in what `read` vs `open` return. As `read` returns *"file bytes for name"* with the `.read()` method already called. While `open` returns a *"file-like object for 'name'"*, a class `ZipExtFile`, that does contain the `.read()` method but this method is not called on the return of `.open()` which means that in order to use it, we have to add it, as I do above.